# Frameset frame cached by Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, browser, caching

I have a html page which contains nested frameset (don't ask why, I'm only servicing the app ;) ). What bothers me, is why FF caches Header.htm file constantly. I had to use clear cache to force browser to download it again. ctrl+f5 didn't help.

```
    <frameset rows="68,*" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="header" src="/Header.htm" scrolling="no" noresize>
    <frame name="footer" src="/Login.aspx?w=<% =company %>&amp;loc=<% =ccdom %>">
</frameset>
```

Any ideas what is responsible for that behaviour? On the other hand, IE downloads the file without a hassle.

Thanks, Pawel

Comment: Ohhh, to be specific: FF console shows that browser doesn't send request for that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
```

to the header.html file

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine for FF, Chrome! On Chrome really nasty stuff was going on - images, tabels got broken etc...
Still, can it be regarded as reliable solution for all browsers?